# Assigning to a two dimensional vector in c++

Tags: c++, 2d-vector

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    vector<vector<int> > v;
    for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
    {
        vector<int> temp;
        for(int j = 0;j < 3;j++)
        {
            temp.push_back(j);
        }
        //cout<<typeid(temp).name()<<endl;
        v[i].push_back(temp);
    }
 }
```

I am trying to assign to a two dimensional vector. I am getting the following error

```
No matching function for call to 
std ::vector<int>::push_back(std::vector<int> &)
```

Comment: `v.push_back(...)`

Comment: `v[i]` accesses out of bounds. The vector has no entries

Comment: `v.push_back(vector)` and `v[i].push_back(int)`

Comment: A "2D vector" is just a vector. So you need to figure out how to add elements to a vector. That's all.

Comment: Just a tip, if you are using c++11 you can use emplace_back

Answer (score 8):

**Problem:** Your vector `v` is empty yet and you can't access `v[i]` without pushing any vector in v.

**Solution:** Replace the statement `v[i].push_back(temp);` with `v.push_back(temp);`

Answer (score 5):

You can follow this process :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<vector<int> > v;
    for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
    {
        vector<int> temp;
        for(int j = 0;j < 3;j++)
        {
            temp.push_back(j);

        }
        //cout<<typeid(temp).name()<<endl;
        v.push_back(temp);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            cout << v[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

`v[0]` is empty, you should use `v.push_back(temp);`

You could use `at` approach to avoid this error:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
   vector <vector <int> > v;
   vector <int> temp;
   v.push_back(temp);
   v.at(COLUMN).push_back(i);
}
```

Then you could access it through:

```
v.at(COLUMN).at(ROWS) = value;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
v[i].push_back(temp);
```

should be

```
v.push_back(temp);
```

`v` is type of `std::vector<vector<int>>`, `v[i]` is type of `std::vector<int>`

Answer (score 4):

You should use `v` instead of `v[i]`. (C++11)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<vector<int> > v;
    for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
    {
        vector<int> temp;
        for(int j = 0;j < 3;j++)
        {
            temp.push_back(j);
        }

        v.push_back(temp);
    }

    for (auto element: v) {
        for (auto atom: element) {
            cout << atom << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Think of it this way: "How do I insert a variable *temp* of type `T` into my vector of `std::vector<T>`?" In your case it is:

```
v.push_back(temp);
```

`T` itself being a vector doesn't make a difference. Then to print out your vector (of vectors) you can use two `for` loops:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < v[i].size(); j++){
        std::cout << v[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Just do it...

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<vector<int> > v;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        vector<int> temp;
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            temp.push_back(j);
        }
        v.push_back(temp);//use v instead of v[i];
    }
}
```